# Animation in react native starts in all of the components instead the starting only in the pressed One

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native and as well to Animations in React Native. What I'm trying to do is to fill the checkbox in it's pressed but the way I did made all the checkboxes fill when I press the Touchable Opacity.
the 'color' value is defined by this
 `const color = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;`
I don't know if this is the best way. I searched through the documentation and saw something like this.

```
    const {
        clean,
        tasks,
        getTasksList,
        edited,
        toogleEdited,
        deleteList,
    } = useContext(listContext);
    const { taskEdited } = useContext(taskContext);
    const [listName, setListName] = useState("");
    const screenHeight = Math.round(Dimensions.get("window").height);
    const colors = useRef(
        Array.from({ length: tasks.length }).fill(new Animated.Value(0))
    );

    async function getListName() {
        setListName(await AsyncStorage.getItem("listName"));
    }
    async function asyncGetTasks() {
        await getTasksList();
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getListName();
        asyncGetTasks();
    }, [edited, taskEdited]);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar hidden />
            <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                        clean();
                        navigation.goBack();
                    }}
                >
                    <MaterialIcons name="arrow-back" size={32} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                        deleteList();
                        clean();
                        navigation.goBack();
                    }}
                >
                    <MaterialIcons name="delete" size={32} color="#bc0000" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.titleContent}>
                <Text style={styles.titleText}>{listName}</Text>
            </View>
            <ScrollView style={{ height: screenHeight }}>
                {tasks.length > 0 ? (
                    tasks.map((item, index) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity key={index} style={styles.task}>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginRight: 8 }}
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        console.log(colors.current[index]);

                                        Animated.timing(colors.current[index], {
                                            toValue: 1,
                                            duration: 1000,
                                        }).start();
                                        toogleEdited();
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <Animated.View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: "#000",
                                            borderWidth: 3,
                                            borderRadius: 100,
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <Animated.View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: "#000",
                                                height: 22,
                                                width: 22,
                                                borderRadius: 100,
                                                opacity: colors.current[index],
                                            }}
                                            nativeID={item._id}
                                        ></Animated.View>
                                    </Animated.View>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <View>
                                    <Text style={styles.taskText}>{item.title}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>

                            <Animated.View
                                style={{
                                    position: "absolute",
                                    alignItems: "center",
                                    alignContent: "center",
                                    opacity: 0.5,
                                    alignSelf: "center",
                                }}
                            >
                                <Text
                                    style={{
                                        color: "#000",
                                        opacity: 0,
                                        fontSize: 32,
                                    }}
                                >
                                    Done!!
                                </Text>
                            </Animated.View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    ))
                ) : (
                    <View style={styles.emptyContent}>
                        <Text style={styles.emptyText}>This list don't have tasks yet</Text>
                    </View>
                )}
            </ScrollView>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: screenHeight - 120,
                    right: 28,
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    width: 50,
                    alignSelf: "flex-end",
                }}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("NewTask")}
            >
                <Image source={PlusImage} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
```

If you don't understand please feel free to ask, my code can be difficult to read but I'm working on that!

edit:
I tried some advises that I got here but still does to all and showed more of the code to be more compreensive

Comment: You are applying animation to every component, Apply on only filled checkboxes.

Comment: I know that but how? @WaheedAkhtar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store all elements as only one `ref`, you should make it more dynamic like that

```
const colors = useRef(Array.from({length: tasks.length} , _ => new Animated.Value(0))).current
```

use `.from({ length }, _ => ...)` for creating an array with unique object for each slot in the array (and not same object pointed by all slots)

Now you able to change only one element in `onPress`

```
onPress={() => {
         console.log(colors[index]);
         Animated.timing(colors[index], {
         toValue: 1,
         duration: 1000,
         }).start();
    }}
```

Another notes,

Don't use `TouchableOpacity` where you don't need `onPress` functionality, it's blocking it children clickability

For achieving animated behavior in `Animated.View`, you should chain the animation value with view `style` prop

```
<Animated.View
    style={{ ...yourStyle... , 
             opacity: colors[index],
       }}
>
```

will create fading animation, while `opacity` will be 0 / 1 accords animation value

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer but it gives me this error : undefined is not an object ( evaluating 'singleValue.stopTracking')

Comment: I appreciate a lot the fact that you are helping me and this is for a final assignment in my school so I'm stressed out.
it still says that is undefined ' colors.current[index]'
maybe the error comes where I declared it because in the console.log it shows this
Object {
  "current": undefined,
}

Comment: Can you create expo snack simulates this behavior?

Comment: I could but I have a node server running to get the data. I can show you the full document if you want

Comment: I will make an expo snack with fake data, I will send the link

Comment: I made the expo snack, the styling isn't the same but it you can see the error 
https://snack.expo.io/x8!GELvW0M

Comment: so to be clear I need to stop using TouchableOpacity, right? Actually I need to change color white to black but didn't know how so I did with opacity. I 'm new at this framework so I'm doing things I shouldn't. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I think I did what you meant but somehow it still does the animation to all components

Comment: thank you, I will do what told me, thanks for wasting your time with me

Comment: Thank you!! Just checked and it works, you saved me!